# Can I pass a PHP function some code to execute via a function argument?

Tags: php

Newbie question...

Is it possible to use a function's argument to pass code to be executed inside the function? Something like...

```
function myfunction($somecode)
{
    $somecode;
}

myfunction("echo 'foo'");
```

Actual scenario: my function performs some image manipulation using Imagick...

```
function myfunction($imagePath)
{
    $image = new Imagick($imagePath);
    $image->gaussianBlurImage(0, 5);
}
myfunction("test.jpg");
```

I'd like to be able to specify the Imagick method to use on the image in a function argument, so I could have something like...

```
function myfunction($imagePath, $method)
{
    $image = new Imagick($imagePath);
    $image->$method;
}
myfunction("test.jpg", "thumbnailImage(100, 100)");
```

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Either use [`eval`](http://php.net/eval) or pass a closure which accepts `$image` as argument.

Comment: @mario what about Variable functions http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sure, would also fit. If it's just a single extra function call, then splitting args into e.g. `myfunc($img, "thumbnail", 100, 100)` would even look tidier.

Comment: Variable functions are good here. Also, perhaps consider being more strict about the `$method`s that you will accept, and run through a `switch()`. That way, you can handle exceptions / unknown methods.

Comment: The method proposed by @CharlieS I feel this is probably the best way, you can insure that you have the proper number/type of arguments, provide defaults, and failing everything else issue meaningful exceptions.

Comment: @Cerulean Try anonymous functions in combination with variable functions.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using anonymous functions and variable variables you could also do this with [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

```
function myfunction($imagePath, $method, array $arguments)
{
    $image = new Imagick($imagePath);
    call_user_func_array([$image, $method], $arguments);
}
myfunction("test.jpg", "thumbnailImage", [100,100]);
```

For additional safety you can check the methods against a whitelist of available methods for the Imagick object.

Comment: Thanks Orangepill, got this to work with a couple of changes to syntax:
    function myfunction($imagePath, $method, array $arguments)
    {
        $image = new Imagick($imagePath);
        call_user_func_array(array($image, $method), $arguments);
    }
    myfunction("test.jpg", "thumbnailImage", array(100, 100));

Comment: If the changes are changing the short array syntax, [] to array() then you are using an [unsupported version of php](http://php.net/supported-versions.php) and should update as soon as possible.

Comment: Sorry, the short array syntax is fine. It's just my code editor that's out of date - it was highlighting the [,] syntax as an error.

Answer (score 0):

*Programming PHP* (Lerdorf, Tatroe, & MacIntyre), 2nd Edition. Ch. 3, p. 73

### Anonymous Functions

"You can create an anonymous function using `create_function()`."

[PHP Manual: create_function()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php)

```
$lamda = create_function( '$param1,param2', 'code;' );
```

But, there is more to know in PHP 5.3 and later.
From example #2 of the PHP Manual under Anonymous Functions.

```
$greet = function($name)
{
    printf("Hello %s\r\n", $name);
};
```

[PHP Manual: Anonymous Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Comment: *If you are using PHP 5.3.0 or newer a native anonymous function should be used instead.*

Comment: yeah, that one I did think about mentioning to the OP ^

Comment: @Marty I assumed one would discover this by clicking on the link.

Comment: Of course, however that information seems important enough that if the link broke for whatever reason or someone passing by was too lazy to click it, a comment still follows to mention it.

Comment: @Marty Good thing Google has a going concern.

Comment: create_function is generally not a good idea because the resources associated with each call are never released. With a closure normal garbage collection rules are in play so the resources would be freed as soon as the function goes out of scope.

Comment: @Orangepill also in the PHP manual. That's why the link is there.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. An anonymous function might well be the best solution, but the examples in the PHP manual make it clear as mud to me how it applies to what I'm trying to do. Can anyone spell it out a bit for a newbie?